# Start an exe. via Windows Service

Tags: c#, service

I'm currently working on a project to automatize my backup to run only under certain circumstances. Therefor I'm writing a Windows Service in C# using Visual Studios 2015. I already got my requirements set and now I can't get my Service to run sdclt.exe (the Microsoft Default Backup). I already searched for a solution but i only found people saying that Windows Services can't start .exe anymore. Does anyone here have an idea how it might still work?

Thank You

Comment: Why can't you simply use Windows Task Scheduler to run your backup?

Comment: It won't work out of the box due to session 0 isolation, google will tell you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726172/launch-process-from-session-0-isolation

Answer (score 0):

you can create BatchFile that Run sdclt.exe or use System.Thredin.Process to Run that exe. use verbs if require to run with administrator rights.